# Howto point two domainnames to one website in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have an NGINX webserver, which is serving multiple websites. For each website, I have a seperate nginx configuration file in the /etc/nginx/sites-available folder.

Now, I would like to have two domainnames (aaa.com and bbb.com) point to the same website. On the registrar side both domain names point to the IP address of my webserver.

On nginx, I have the following configuration:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        root /var/www/html/aaa.com/public_html;
        index index.html index.php index.htm;

        server_name aaa.com www.aaa.com bbb.com www.bbb.com;

        <rest of the configuration
}
```

I can reach now www.aaa.com but accessing the website via bbb.com does not work.

Should I create a seperate config file (in sites-available) for bbb.com and point to the location of the website in /var/www/html and enable it in sites-enabled?

Comment: This should be enough. What exactly "does not work"  mean (an error, wrong homepage,..?)

Comment: My server is running on digitalocean and I'm getting a default index page saying "Please log into your Droplet with SSH to configure the LEMP installation". Should I add it to 'sites-available' and 'sites-enabled'?

Comment: What if you try with https: `https://bbb.com`? (the above nginx conf will affect only https virtual host, there should be another `server` block with `listen 80` for plain http)